# How do I print RAISE NOTICE from PostgreSQL in Airflow logs

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am trying to print out some debugging data from the RAISE NOTICE in the Postgresql stored procedure in Airflow. I remember that a few years ago this was done by default, at least in the official docker image back then. I'm guessing things changed in the later airflow versions.

Currently I am using airflow docker image "apache/airflow:2.8.1-python3.10" which comes with "apache-airflow-providers-postgres==5.10.0". Postgresql is version 12.

Comment: If that's for debugging a procedure you're working on now, it might be easier to write your info to a table, adding a `clock_timestamp()` and inspect it there, instead of referring to the airflow log each time. If you're trying to catch debugging notice-level log broadcasted on prod, I'd guess it might be down to [`client_min_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) or [`log_min_messages`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHEN).